# Auth::Attempt without password if its social login

Tags: laravel, authentication, hash, passwords

my normal login functionality is working fine. but I am trying to login with social login so I need to do Auth Attempt on successful social login to manage Auth::User()->id throughout the application.
code
I am not able to compare the hash password

```
if(user is already register still user tried social login with same email){
  //here i am trying to get that email id password 
  $userFromEmail = DB::table('users')->where('email', 'user@gmail.com')->first();
   if(Auth::attempt([ 'email'=> $userFromEmail->email,'password'=> $userFromEmail->password  ])){
      dd(Auth::User()->id);
    }else{
        echo("not login");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it instead of doing Auth::attempy(email,password) i am authenticating by Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);